# How to check Result is numeric or letters in crystal reports,if Result is numeric and exceeds Minvalue or Maxvalue and that result should be on Bold

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Am trying to get the value in crystal report if numeric or else exceeds minval and maxval that result should come in bold

**My code is like this**

```
IF(ISNUMERIC({Result})  /*if result is numeric*/
and {Result}<{Minimum Value} or >{Maximum value} /*if Result Exceeds min or maxvalue */
THEN 
crbold({Result})
else
({Result}))
```

Help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work your condition is wrong.

```
IF(
TONUMBER({SP_Lab_GetOPLaboratoryDeptWiseReport;1.Result}) <= 
{SP_Lab_GetOPLaboratoryDeptWiseReport;1.MinValue}
OR
TONUMBER({SP_Lab_GetOPLaboratoryDeptWiseReport;1.Result}) >=
{SP_Lab_GetOPLaboratoryDeptWiseReport;1.Maxvalue}
)
THEN
" " & "<b>" & {SP_Lab_GetOPLaboratoryDeptWiseReport;1.Result} & "</b>"
ELSE
{SP_Lab_GetOPLaboratoryDeptWiseReport;1.Result}
```

**Then Format your field to htmltext**